# range in unknown sheet

Tags: excel, vba, range

i'm working in one macro but i have a problem,
i have one Range named "Sheetlist", the problem is that i opened a chain of files form my macro, and this range is not in the same cell or in the same sheet (some times the sheet is named "sheet 1" or "page1" or other names,
My question is, how can i know the sheet name in where is this Range ("Sheet Name")

Comment: `range("Sheet Name").Parent.name`

Comment: ^ and handle run-time error 9

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner, looks good, i thinks that .Parent.name is all that i need =)